# Improving the accuracy of Iris ML model using Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I'm beginner in Python and ML. I was practising this Iris Data set to create a ML model using tensor flow 2.0.

I parsed the csv and trained the model using the dataset. I'm able to get 90 % training accuracy and 91 % validation accuracy during my model creation.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

csv_data = np.loadtxt('iris_training.csv',delimiter=',')
target_all = csv_data[:,-1]

csv_data = csv_data[:,0:-1]

# Shuffling the input
shuffled_indices = np.arange(csv_data.shape[0])
np.random.shuffle(shuffled_indices)

shuffled_inputs = csv_data[shuffled_indices]
shuffled_targets = target_all[shuffled_indices]

# Standardize the Inputs
shuffled_inputs = preprocessing.scale(shuffled_inputs)

# Split date into train , validation and test
total_count = shuffled_inputs.shape[0]
train_data_count = int(0.8*total_count)
validation_data_count = int(0.1*total_count)
test_data_count = total_count - train_data_count - validation_data_count

train_inputs = shuffled_inputs[:train_data_count]
train_targets = shuffled_targets[:train_data_count]

validation_inputs = shuffled_inputs[train_data_count:train_data_count+validation_data_count]
validation_targets = shuffled_targets[train_data_count:train_data_count+validation_data_count]

test_inputs = shuffled_inputs[train_data_count+validation_data_count:]
test_targets = shuffled_targets[train_data_count+validation_data_count:]


print(len(train_inputs))
print(len(validation_inputs))
print(len(test_inputs))

# Model Creation
input_size = 4
hidden_layer_size = 100
output_size = 3

model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, input_dim=input_size,     activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(hidden_layer_size, activation=tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(output_size, activation=tf.nn.softmax))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(train_inputs,train_targets, epochs=10, validation_data=(validation_inputs, validation_targets), verbose=2)

prediction = model.predict(test_inputs)
```

Point me if there is something in my code that i could do to improve the accuracy of my model for this simple Iris Dataset.

File Used for training my Model  : [Iris Csv](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aEsoeiAi6n9Ito-135oz31CIQHNEozdM/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: that isn't an issue of pycharm. its simply an index out of range for `target` and/or `outs`

Comment: your usage of `evaluate` is wrong. you are probably looking for [predict](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict)

Comment: @luigigi If I `test_loss, test_accuracy = model.predict(test_inputs)` Im getting  `line 78, in <module>
    test_loss, test_accuracy = model.predict(test_inputs)
ValueError: too many values to unpack Issue` Could you help me in this

Comment: yes, because `predict` only have one return value. use sth like `predictions = model.predict(test_inputs)
`

Comment: @luigigi yes i was looking for `predict` and it has only one return value. Thanks for ur help man. Now i'm getting distributed probabilities from my model.  Is there any way to improve accuracy of my model ?

Comment: No, sorry. just here for the coding error

Comment: @luigigi Thank you man. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

As for your model, you can try to do ***hyperparameters tuning***,

- Setting the learning rate to a lower value
- **Increase** the epoch
- Add **more training dataset** since you have a small set of the dataset.

The **neural network shines** when there is a ***good amount of data*** for the training.

You can also add **more layers** to the model, add **dropouts to avoid overfitting**
as well as using **different activation functions**.

These are the common factors that affect model performance.